# How to filter sub array and project multiple matching values of a matching document in mongoDb

Tags: mongodb

I have a structure like:

```
{
_id: ObjectId("doc1"),
    SubArrayDocs: [
        {
        _id: ObjectId("subDoc1"),
        name: "name1"
        },
        {
        _id: ObjectId("subDoc2"),
        name: "name2"
        },
        {
        _id: ObjectId("subDoc3"),
        name: "name3"
        }
    ]
},
{
    _id: ObjectId("doc2"),
    ....
}
```

I would like to match doc1 and when projecting it to return filtered SubArrayDocs by _id so that I get only subDoc1 and subDoc2.

I've tried a few things and I can either get all subArrayDocs or just first one that matches $in operator.

Is there a way to filter Subarray documents on a matching document so that I get back multiple subarray documents, without using aggregation framework.

Expected result for given orgId: "doc1" and
sub array docs: "subDoc1, subDoc2" should be:

```
{
    _id: ObjectId("doc1"),
        SubArrayDocs: [
            {
            _id: ObjectId("subDoc1"),
            name: "name1"
            },
            {
            _id: ObjectId("subDoc2"),
            name: "name2"
            }
        ]
    }
```

So basically, get the doc but with filtered contents of its sub array.
I've tried everything that *I* could with $in $elemMatch, projections and positional params.

Comment: Can you show us the code for the few things that you have tried and as well as the expected result?

Comment: First your `ObjectId` is invalid

Comment: No. You can only ever restrict the contents of an array to be just the first matching element. You will need to change the document structure or use the aggregation framework.

Comment: @Michael thanks for noticing... but I did that on purpose....because there's no point in generating or simulating 24 characters long ObjectId in this case, IMHO

Comment: @wdberkeley thanks... yes or no, that's what I was looking for... in case I've missed something